# getting auth failure on salt-cloud command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I'm using salt stack and I want to try and provision new EC2 instances using the salt-cloud command. But I'm getting an auth failure on salt-cloud command:

```
[root@salt:~] #salt-cloud -p base_ec2_public ops.example.com
[ERROR   ] AWS Response Status Code and Error: [401 401 Client Error: Unauthorized] {'Errors': {'Error': {'Message': 'AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials', 'Code': 'AuthFailure'}}, 'RequestID': '3a5e33e2-d1a9-44fa-983c-26691d4f8ee7'}
[ERROR   ] AWS Response Status Code and Error: [401 401 Client Error: Unauthorized] {'Errors': {'Error': {'Message': 'AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials', 'Code': 'AuthFailure'}}, 'RequestID': '163079c6-2b79-4301-80c8-77ba0d7c896d'}
[ERROR   ] There was a profile error: string indices must be integers, not str
```

This is my /etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/aws.conf file

```
----
my-ec2-us-east-public-ips:
  # Set up the location of the salt master
  #
  minion:
    master: salt.example.com

  # Set up grains information, which will be common for all nodes
  # using this provider
  grains:
    node_type: broker
    release: 1.0.1

  # Specify whether to use public or private IP for deploy script.
  #
  # Valid options are:
  #     private_ips - The salt-cloud command is run inside the EC2
  #     public_ips - The salt-cloud command is run outside of EC2
  #
  ssh_interface: public_ips

  # Optionally configure the Windows credential validation number of
  # retries and delay between retries.  This defaults to 10 retries
  # with a one second delay betwee retries
  win_deploy_auth_retries: 10
  win_deploy_auth_retry_delay: 1

  # Set the EC2 access credentials (see below)
  #
  id: "REDACTED"
  key: "REDACTED"

  # Make sure this key is owned by root with permissions 0400.
  #
  private_key: /etc/salt/my_test_key.pem
  keyname: my_test_key
  securitygroup: default

  # Optionally configure default region
  # Use salt-cloud --list-locations <provider> to obtain valid regions
  #
  location: us-east-1
  availability_zone: us-east-1a

  #
  ssh_username: ec2-user

  # Optionally add an IAM profile
  iam_profile: 'arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:user/bluethundr'

  driver: ec2


my-ec2-us-east-private-ips:
  # Set up the location of the salt master
  #
  minion:
   master: salt.example.com
  # Specify whether to use public or private IP for deploy script.
  #
  # Valid options are:
  #     private_ips - The salt-master is also hosted with EC2
  #     public_ips - The salt-master is hosted outside of EC2
  #
  ssh_interface: private_ips

  # Optionally configure the Windows credential validation number of
  # retries and delay between retries.  This defaults to 10 retries
  # with a one second delay betwee retries
  win_deploy_auth_retries: 10
  win_deploy_auth_retry_delay: 1

  # Set the EC2 access credentials (see below)
  #
  id: "REDACTED" 
  key: "REDACTED"

  # Make sure this key is owned by root with permissions 0400.
  #
  private_key: /etc/salt/my_test_key.pem
  keyname: my_test_key

  # This one should NOT be specified if VPC was not configured in AWS to be
  # the default. It might cause an error message which says that network
  # interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be specified
  # on the same request.
  #
  securitygroup: default

  # Optionally configure default region
  #
  location: us-east-1
  availability_zone: us-east-1a

  # Configure which user to use to run the deploy script. This setting is
  # dependent upon the AMI that is used to deploy. It is usually safer to
  # configure this individually in a profile, than globally. Typical users
  # are:
  #
  # Amazon Linux -> ec2-user
  # RHEL         -> ec2-user
  # CentOS       -> ec2-user
  # Ubuntu       -> ubuntu
  #
  ssh_username: ec2-user

  # Optionally add an IAM profile
  iam_profile: 'arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:user/bluethundr'

  driver: ec2
```

And this is my /etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/aws_pofiles.conf

```
base_ec2:
  provider: my-ec2-us-east-public-ips
  image: ami-869a9cee
  size: t2.micro
  ssh_username: ec2-user

base_ec2_private:/et
  provider: my-ec2-us-east-private-ips
  image: ami-869a9cee
  size: t2.micro
  ssh_username: ec2-user

base_ec2_public:
  provider: my-ec2-us-east-public-ips
  image: ami-e565ba8c
  size: t2.micro
  ssh_username: ec2-user

base_ec2_db:
  provider: my-ec2-us-east-public-ips
  image: ami-e565ba8c
  size: m1.xlarge
  ssh_username: ec2-user
  volumes:
    - { size: 10, device: /dev/sdf }
    - { size: 10, device: /dev/sdg, type: io1, iops: 1000 }
    - { size: 10, device: /dev/sdh, type: io1, iops: 1000 }
    - { size: 10, device: /dev/sdi, tags: {"Environment": "production"} }
  # optionally add tags to profile:
  tag: {'Environment': 'production', 'Role': 'database'}
  # force grains to sync after install
  sync_after_install: grains

base_ec2_vpc:
  provider: my-ec2-us-east-public-ips
  image: ami-a73264ce
  size: m1.xlarge
  ssh_username: ec2-user
  script:  /etc/salt/cloud.deploy.d/user_data.sh
  network_interfaces:
    - DeviceIndex: 0
      PrivateIpAddresses:
        - Primary: True
      #auto assign public ip (not EIP)
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: True
      SubnetId: subnet-813d4bbf
      SecurityGroupId:
        - sg-750af413
  del_root_vol_on_destroy: True
  del_all_vol_on_destroy: True
  volumes:
    - { size: 10, device: /dev/sdf }
    - { size: 10, device: /dev/sdg, type: io1, iops: 1000 }
    - { size: 10, device: /dev/sdh, type: io1, iops: 1000 }
  tag: {'Environment': 'production', 'Role': 'database'}
  sync_after_install: grains
```

Here's some debug output of the command I'm trying to get working:

```
[root@salt:~] #salt-cloud -p base_ec2_public ops.example.com  -l debug
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/cloud
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: salt.example.com
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /etc/salt/cloud.providers
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/aws.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/aws.conf
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /etc/salt/cloud.profiles
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/aws_profiles.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/aws_profiles.conf
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/cloud
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[INFO    ] salt-cloud starting
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad parallels.avail_sizes: 'parallels' __virtual__ returned False
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded parallels.avail_locations
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded proxmox.avail_sizes
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.destroy: 'saltify.destroy' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_sizes: 'saltify.avail_sizes' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_images: 'saltify.avail_images' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_locations: 'saltify.avail_locations' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded rackspace.reboot
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded openstack.list_locations
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded rackspace.list_locations
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad parallels.avail_sizes: 'parallels' __virtual__ returned False
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded parallels.avail_locations
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded proxmox.avail_sizes
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.destroy: 'saltify.destroy' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_sizes: 'saltify.avail_sizes' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_images: 'saltify.avail_images' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad saltify.avail_locations: 'saltify.avail_locations' is not available.
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded rackspace.reboot
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded openstack.list_locations
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded rackspace.list_locations
[DEBUG   ] Using AWS endpoint: ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[DEBUG   ] AWS Request: https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2014-10-01
[DEBUG   ] AWS Response Status Code: 401
[ERROR   ] AWS Response Status Code and Error: [401 401 Client Error: Unauthorized] {'Errors': {'Error': {'Message': 'AWS was not able to validate the provided acce
ss credentials', 'Code': 'AuthFailure'}}, 'RequestID': '0f483305-6cb2-4c09-ae2f-ec804fd3beea'}
[DEBUG   ] Failed to execute 'ec2.list_nodes()' while querying for running nodes: An error occurred while listing nodes: AWS was not able to validate the provided a
ccess credentials
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/__init__.py", line 2383, in run_parallel_map_providers_query
    cloud.clouds[data['fun']]()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py", line 3496, in list_nodes
    nodes = list_nodes_full(get_location())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py", line 3346, in list_nodes_full
    return _list_nodes_full(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py", line 3436, in _list_nodes_full
    instances['error']['Errors']['Error']['Message']
SaltCloudSystemExit: An error occurred while listing nodes: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
[DEBUG   ] Generating minion keys for 'ops.jokefire.com'
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded cloud.fire_event
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new IPCClient for path: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'profile': 'base_ec2_public', 'event': 'starting create', '_stamp': '2016-09-13T19:24:13.555913', 'name': 'ops.jokefire.com', 'pr
ovider': 'my-ec2-us-east-public-ips:ec2'}
[INFO    ] Creating Cloud VM ops.jokefire.com in us-east-1
[DEBUG   ] Using AWS endpoint: ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[DEBUG   ] AWS Request: https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeAvailabilityZones&Filter.0.Name=region-name&Filter.0.Value.0=us-east-1&Version=2014-10-0
1
[DEBUG   ] AWS Response Status Code: 401
[ERROR   ] AWS Response Status Code and Error: [401 401 Client Error: Unauthorized] {'Errors': {'Error': {'Message': 'AWS was not able to validate the provided acce
ss credentials', 'Code': 'AuthFailure'}}, 'RequestID': 'e9912cf2-2e9b-496f-b607-4b9bae8b8938'}
[ERROR   ] There was a profile error: string indices must be integers, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/cli.py", line 284, in run
    self.config.get('names')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/__init__.py", line 1454, in run_profile
    ret[name] = self.create(vm_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/__init__.py", line 1284, in create
    output = self.clouds[func](vm_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py", line 2512, in create
    data, vm_ = request_instance(vm_, location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py", line 1742, in request_instance
    az_ = get_availability_zone(vm_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py", line 1094, in get_availability_zone
    zones = _list_availability_zones(vm_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py", line 1242, in _list_availability_zones
    ret[zone['zoneName']] = zone['zoneState']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Can someone take a stab and let me know why I'm getting auth failures? The redacted AWS keys were taken straight from the AWS interface and copied into the cloud.providers file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the EC2 credentials are not provided. You may need to check the Key/ID of the EC2 credentials, and their policy.

For credentials, replace "REDACTED" string with your real key/ID.

Comment: Yep! I used the key name as listed in the aws web UI and that solved that problem. Obviously, I'm listing the keys here as REDACTED to not show them to the whole world. The real key/id isin the config. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Then in this case, you can try upgrade salt-cloud via

```salt-cloud -u```

and try again.

Comment: cool, thanks! But salt cloud is working like a charm now! The main thing I had to do to get it working was cloud profiles working correctly and make sure my provider was good. I had to verify my aws keypair was working correctly and that I could launch ec2 instances on the aws command line. For that I had to make sure my clock was synced via NTP. Once I was able to do that salt-cloud started working perfectly! Thanks for your input!